# Magento design configuration only showing 1 record

Tags: magento2

I'm on Magento 2.3.3 and my Design Configuration page within the Admin (Content > Design > Configuration) only shows one record:
[image]

It used to show 3 similar to this image but with my website, store and store view names listed: [image]

I have tried clearing cache and running the reindexer command (bin/magento indexer:reindex design_config_grid), but no luck.

My "design_config_grid_flat" table appears to have all of the correct values (my theme_id is '4': [image]

It appears that only entity_id 1 from the table above is getting displayed. Any suggestions on what I am missing? I can't figure out why all 3 rows are not showing. I appreciate any help / suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website is on Single Store mode, that's why you are not able to see all stores here, follow below mentioned steps:

1. On the Admin sidebar, tap Stores. Then under Settings, choose Configuration.

[image]

2. Expand GENERAL tab and click General.

[image]

3. Scroll down to the bottom of the page, and open the Single-Store Mode section.
4. Set Enable Single-Store Mode option to **No**.
   [image]
5. Press the Save Config button.
6. Refresh the cache, do the following:

Tap the Cache Management link in the system message at the top of the page.
Mark the Page Cache checkbox.
With Actions set to “Refresh,” tap  Submit .

Comment: I will courier a beer to you mate. +1